# Merge an array by key and create an new array for values

Tags: php, arrays, merge, key

I have an array that I need to merge by key and create a new array with the values for that key. I've searched and searched without result. Any help would be great!

Original array

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
    (
        [name] => Key 1
        [value] => Value 1
    )

    [2] => Array
    (
        [name] => Key 1
        [value] => Value 2
    )

    [3] => Array
    (
        [name] => Key 2
        [value] => Value 1
    )

    [4] => Array
    (
        [name] => Key 1
        [value] => Value 3
    )

    [5] => Array
    (
        [name] => Key 2
        [value] => Value 2
    )
)
```

Final array should look like this

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
    (
        [name] => Key 1
        [value] => Array
        (
            [0] => Value 1

            [1] => Value 2

            [2] => Value 3
        )
    )

    [1] => Array
    (
        [name] => Key 2
        [value] => Array
        (
            [0] => Value 1

            [1] => Value 2
        )
    )
)
```

Comment: As previously asked, what have you tried, post some working code, does not matter is incorrect, is a starting point and maybe you are not far from the solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php 
$array =    Array
(
    0 => Array
    (
        'name' => 'Key 1',
        'value' => 'Value 1'
    ),

    2 => Array
    (
        'name' => 'Key 1',
        'value' => 'Value 2'
    ),

    3 => Array
    (
        'name' => 'Key 2',
        'value' => 'Value 1'
    ),

    4 => Array
    (
        'name' => 'Key 1',
        'value' => 'Value 3'
    ),

    5 => Array
    (
        'name' => 'Key 2',
        'value' => 'Value 2'
    )
);
$tmpArray = array(); 
foreach ($array as $smallArray) {
if(!is_array($tmpArray[$smallArray['name']]))
    $tmpArray[$smallArray['name']] = array();

$tmpArray[$smallArray['name']][] = $smallArray['value'];
}
$finalArray = array();
foreach ($tmpArray as $key => $value) {
    $someArray['name'] = $key;
    $someArray['value'] = $value;
    $finalArray[] = $someArray;
}

print_r($finalArray);
```

i wrote the solution for you but next time you should try your self first

Comment: Belive you me i've tried! :) I sat up all night testing different stuff. I finally managed to solve it. Doesn't look like your code but it also works. Thank you for your help! :)